# How many concurrent request IIS 6.0 can response

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, hosting, asp.net-2.0

Asp.net website, which i am making plan for hosting at Windows Server 2003. Here i would like to know that how many concurrent request IIS 6.0 can serve?

Actually in my website the number of registration at the time of deployment is around eight thousand and the growth rate is about 100%.

Is there any standard formula by which i can calculate the number of simultaneous request IIS 6.0 can server, because it can help me to calculate the performance of website.

Answer (score 0):

Performance isn't a function of only IIS. It has to do with what type of hardware you are running on, what your web application is actually doing and your internet connectivity. Your best bet is to look in to benchmarking tools and try to extrapolate from there, but no, there is no standard formula, since there are so many different variables that affect performance so greatly.

Comment: Hi, Let say i improved my server and application performance as best as possible and i have enough bandwidth at server, then can i say that any number of parallel request for any size of page is serverd per second by server? 

I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you use a load testing tool to check the number of concurrent requests vs. response time and find a figure that you're happy with. You should also make sure that your application can work in a web-farm environment if you need to add more physical servers down the track.

Comment: Thanks,

Can you send me tool which i should used for load testing?
I have one question as you can see in reply of Adam

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2008 or 2005 have a look at the "Tester Edition" as it comes with a load testing tool.

Comment: Hi, Let say i improved my server and application performance as best as possible and i have enough bandwidth at server, then can i say that any number of parallel request for any size of page is serverd per second by server? I don't think so...